# How to get the file name from a ambiguous url?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

In bit of a snag here and I'm unable to find documentation with details to get around this issue.
I am aware of how to get a file name from a URL if the URL looks like this for example:

```
https://preview.redd.it/award_images/t5_q0gj4/ks45ij6w05f61_oldHugz.png
```

But my issue is, how to get the filename if the URL is ambiguous and has no path embeded in it, for example:

```
https://codeload.github.com/ecthros/uncaptcha2/zip/master
```

Almost every method I know of returns 'master' as the file name, where as the real file name is 'uncaptcha2-master.zip'. And this issue just gets worse with more complex URLs. Obviously I can download the file and get the file name like that, but the issue is I have a few thousand URLs and getting the file names like that would mean I would have to wait forever and be wiling to use all my bandwidth and storage to do so, so that is not a viable option in my case.

If anyone has any ideas of how to overcome this please let me know

Comment: You can’t since there is no “file” when URLs are concerned. Accessing a URL can produce whatever results so there’s no way to know, unless you know the logic behind them.

Answer (score 0):

When you access a url that is not a file like `https://codeload.github.com/ecthros/uncaptcha2/zip/master` server processes the request and returns the file url based on the request. so you can't just guess the process algorithm and your are not able to catch the filename unless you find the logic of process by generalizing. but in most cases you can't retrieve the filename based on endpoint.

Comment: I get what you mean and that in a way, kinda makes this issue frustrating as the only workaround I can see is either download the file once the server sends process the request and get the file name that way or start downloading the file and interrupt the download once you get the file name. Either way I have to wait a much longer for each file, and that just adds up when you have a few thousand URLS.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the filename from response http headers using the module `cgi` to parse the header and then getting the parameter `filename`, this code returns 'uncaptcha2-master.zip'

```
import requests
import cgi
URL = 'https://codeload.github.com/ecthros/uncaptcha2/zip/master'
response = requests.get(URL)
header = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition', '')
_, params = cgi.parse_header(header)
filename = params['filename']
# uncaptcha2-master.zip
print(filename)
```

About the parameter filename:

> Is followed by a string containing the original name of the file transmitted. The filename is always optional and must not be used blindly by the application: path information should be stripped, and conversion to the server file system rules should be done. This parameter provides mostly indicative information

You can get more information about this parameter and the Content-Disposition response header [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually tried it a bit before, and It is true it works for this particular URL, but in cases where the server does not return a 'Content-Disposition' in the response header, this method does not work. For example download URL for files stored in Google Cloud including Youtube videos, Drive and same goes for most of AWS content delivery system.